# "categorie.forEach is not a function"

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, foreach

I'm trying to display `this.cat` in a dropdown but I get this error :

> categorie.forEach is not a function

This is my code :

```
  getCategories(){
    this.policeService.getCategoriesList().subscribe(
      data => {
      this.categories=data;
      console.log(this.categories);
      },
     error =>
      console.log(error));
  }

changeCategories() {
    this.sourceCategories.length = 0;
    this.categories.forEach((categorie) => {
        categorie.forEach((categorie) => this.brancheid = categorie.branche.id);

        if(this.policeform.get("branche").value.id == this.brancheid) {
            this.sourceCategories.push(categorie);
            this.cat = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.sourceCategories));
        }
    })
}
```

[image: this is my categories list]

Comment: What is the data in `categories`?

Comment: `categorie` is not an iterable object or array.

Comment: Where have you defined categories list?

Comment: also put categories example  in question. And dont give same name to foreach elenent like categorie

Comment: Need Categories Array in question.

Comment: By the way, just an FYI but the singular form of the word "categories" is _"category"_, not _"categorie"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your categories array seems like array in the form of object.

Try Array Prototype forEach method..  it will work .

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.categories, categorie=> {
  console.log(categorie)
});
```

Comment: I really wonder how this solved your observable problem and difference from your first loop ? @Lamyae Lac

Answer (score 0):

No need of for each in categorie.

```
changeCategories(){
    this.sourceCategories.length=0;
    this.categories.forEach((categorie)=>{
      this.brancheid=categorie.branche.id;
      if(this.policeform.get("branche").value.id==this.brancheid){
        this.sourceCategories.push(categorie);
        this.cat=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.sourceCategories));
      }
   })
   }
```